# Is there a way to increase Azure VM OS disk size via terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, virtual-machine

The Azure VM was created via terraform code with OS disk size set as 256 GB.

Is there a way to increase the OS disk space (using terraform) without recreating the VM?

My current terraform code is

```
os_disk {
    name                 = "disk23"
    disk_size_gb         = 256
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
  }
```

Comment: what does terraform plan show when you try? does it tell you the vm will be replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the value on `disk_size_gb` and running `terraform plan` shows no destruction but just a new change.
Changed to the desired value.

Comment: if TF plan shows no destruction, it should be fine. 
Please note that increasing the OS disk size may require the VM to be restarted for the changes to take effect.

I would follow:
1) make a snapshot of the VM disk (before applying point3)
2) create a sandbox environment trying to replicate all the steps involved into the disk increase.
3) If point2 expectations are fine, proceeding applying the steps to the prod VM.